# Recurrence relation of type $a_{n+1} = a^2_{n}-2a_{n}+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ is defined by $a_{n+1} = a^2_{n}-2a_{n}+2\forall n\geq 0$ and $a_{0} =4$
>
> And another sequence $\{b_{n}\}$ defined by the formula $\displaystyle b_{n} = \frac{2b_{0}b_{1}b_{2}..........b_{n-1}}{a_{n}}\forall n\geq 1$ and $\displaystyle  b_{0}=\frac{1}{2}$,Then
>
> $(a)$ value of $a_{10}$
>
> $(b)\;\; $ The value of $n$ for which $\displaystyle b_{n} = \frac{3280}{3281}$
>
> $(c)$ The Sequence $\{b_{n}\}$ satisfy the recurrence formula
>
> $\bf{Options::}$
>
> $(1)\; \displaystyle b_{n+1} = \frac{2b_{n}}{1-b^2_{n}}\;\;\;\;\;\; (b)\; \displaystyle b_{n+1} = \frac{2b_{n}}{1b^2_{n}}\;\;\;\;\;\; (c)\; \displaystyle b_{n+1} = \frac{b_{n}}{1+2b^2_{n}}\; (d)\; \displaystyle b_{n+1} = \frac{b_{n}}{1-2b^2_{n}}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Given $a_{n+1} = a^2_{n}-2a_{n}+2 = \left(a_{n}-1\right)^2+1$

So $a_{1} = (a_{0}-1)^2+1=(4-1)^2+1=10$

Similarly $a_{2} = (a_{1}-1)^2+1 = 9^2+1 = 82$

Similarly $a_{3} = (81)^2+1 = $

But Calculation like this is very complex, Plz help me how can i solve above problems, Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify the notation for option $(b)$ ?

Comment: To  Claude Leibovici I have edited my post , plz see it.

Comment: This is a totally different story !! Please, fix the edit of option $(b)$. I shall try to have a look to your **new** problem. Cheers :-)

Comment: Having to go very shortly, I computed the first terms and they are $$\left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{10},\frac{1}{820},\frac{1}{53808400}\right\}$$ So, I still do not understand how you could get the famous $\frac{3280}{3281}$. Looking at the different options, using $b_{n+1} = \frac{2b_{n}}{1+b^2_{n}}$, $b_3$ is equal to it but this does not match the definition. I suppose that we still have a problem. I am not surprised by the fact that you are in trouble. Good luck.

Comment: Admitting that there is a limit for $b_n$, it can only be $1$ if option $(b)$.

Comment: When you will get the answer of the second problem, please, let me know. I really would like to identify the story around the definition of $b_n$. Thanks.

Comment: No Claude Leibovici i will conform  $(b)$ from original source, Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Define $c_{n}=a_{n}-1$. Note that $c_{n+1}=c_{n}^{2}$. Then,
$c_{4} = c_{3}^{2} = c_{2}^{4} = c_{1}^{8} = c_{0}^{16} = 3^{16}$, so $a_{4}=3^{16}+1$.

Comment: Thanks LaloVelasco would you like to explain me $(b)$ and $(c)$ parts.

Answer (score 3):

For the first problem, as LaloVelasco answered, you have $$c_{n+1}=c_{n}^{2}$$ Take logarithms $$\log(c_{n+1})=2\log(c_n)$$ Define $d_n=\log(c_n)$ which makes $$d_{n+1}=2d_n\implies d_n=k\, 2^{n-1}\implies c_n=e^{k\, 2^{n-1}}\implies a_n=1+e^{k\, 2^{n-1}}$$ and $k=2 \log (a_0-1)$ which makes $$a_n=(a_0-1)^{2^n}+1$$ and then the result for any $n$.

Then, $a_{10}=(a_0-1)^{1024}+1$.

Comment: Thanks Claude Leibovici would you like to explain me $(b)$ and $(c)$ parts.

Comment: @juantheron. Are you sure about the definition of  $\{b_{n}\}$ ?

Comment: Sorry Claude Leibovici, I have edited

Comment: With the current Definition of $b_n$ we can't calculate $b_1$

Comment: @juantheron. I "prefer" this one but I am really in trouble with it. Did you compute the first terms ? There is a quite clear pattern but I don't see where or how we could find $b_{n} = \frac{3280}{3281}$. I am stuck and I shall wait for an answer too !

Comment: It's not so hard to get that $b_n=b_{n-2}^2$, but with just $b_0$ you can't Make a Formular bcs we don't know how it will look like if n is odd

Comment: It seems that $b_{2n-1}=\frac 1 {b_{2n}}$ and using HeatTheIce's result, I still do not see how we could get such a number. Starting from $0$, for the first terms, the sequence is $$\left\{\frac{1}{2},4,\frac{1}{4},16,\frac{1}{16},256,\frac{1}{256},65536,\frac{1}{6
   5536}\right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

For the second recurrence
$$
b_{\,n + 1}  = \frac{{2\prod\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n - 1} {b_{\,k} } }}
{{b_{\,n} }}
$$
we have
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  b_{\,0}  = 1/2 \hfill \\
  b_{\,1}  = \frac{2}
{{b_{\,0} }} = 4 \hfill \\
  b_{\,n + 1}  = \frac{{2\prod\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n - 1} {b_{\,k} } }}
{{b_{\,n} }} = \frac{{2\prod\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n - 1} {b_{\,k} } }}
{{\frac{{2\prod\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n - 2} {b_{\,k} } }}
{{b_{\,n - 1} }}}} = b_{\,n - 1} ^2  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
assuming that, in deducing $b_1$, we can adopt *empty product = $1$*

Comment: May be, there is a trap in this problem. If we assume $b_1=x$, then the sequence is $$\left\{\frac{1}{2},x,\frac{1}{x},x^2,\frac{1}{x^2},x^4,\frac{1}{x^4},x^8,\frac{1}{x
   ^8},x^{16},\frac{1}{x^{16}}\right\}$$

Comment: To G Cab I have edited my psot, plz see it.