# Write $b_{n+1}$ in terms of $b_n$, where $b_n=\frac{2a_0a_1a_2...a_{n-1}}{a_n}\forall n\ge1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, recurrence-relations, recursion

> The sequence $\{a_n\}$ is defined by formula $a_0=4$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n^2-2a_n+2$ for $n\ge0$. Let the sequence $\{b_n\}$ is defined by formula $b_0=\frac12$ and $b_n=\frac{2a_0a_1a_2...a_{n-1}}{a_n}\forall n\ge1$. Write the recurrence formula for the sequence $\{b_n\}$ i.e. write $b_{n+1}$ in terms of $b_n$

**My Attempt:**

$a_{n+1}=(a_n-1)^2+1$

So, $a_1=10, a_2=82, a_3=6562$

$b_1=\frac45, b_2=\frac{40}{41}, b_3=\frac{3280}{3281}$

How to write recurrence formula?

Comment: see https://oeis.org/A059918 https://oeis.org/A059917

Comment: @aarbee FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24b_n%3D%5Cfrac%7B2a_0a_1a_2...a_%7Bn-1%7D%7D%7Ba_n%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a_%7Bn%2B1%7D%3Da_n%5E2-2a_n%2B2%24&p=1), there's the quite similar [Recurrence relation of type $a_{n+1} = a^2_{n}-2a_{n}+2$](/q/1932519), with the major difference being the definition of $b_n$ has factors of $b_i$ instead of $a_i$ in the numerator. In your version, it's fairly simple to get $b_{n+1}$ in terms of $b_n$. Is there any chance you miswrote your problem, with it supposed to use $b_i$ instead in the numerator?

Comment: @JohnOmielan there is a possibility, there is a typo in the linked post, not in mine. Because in the linked post, they are also asking for $n$ such that $b_n=\frac{3280}{3281}$. With my statement, we are getting $n=3$. Would we get that with the statement in the linked post?

Comment: @aarbee As far as I can tell, there's no $n$ where $b_n = \frac{3280}{3281}$ based on the recursive relation in that linked post, e.g., as explained in [Claude Leibovici's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1932519/recurrence-relation-of-type-a-n1-a2-n-2a-n2#comment3970430_1932519). Thus, your suggestion that the linked post has the typo instead is quite plausible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $a_{n+1}-1=(a_n-1)^2$ for all $n\ge 0$, it follows that $a_n-1=(a_0-1)^{2^n}=3^{2^n}$, i.e. $a_n=3^{2^n}+1$. Thus,
$$
2a_0a_1\dots a_{n-1}=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(3^{2^j}+1\right)=(3-1)(3+1)(3^2+1)(3^{2^2}+1)\dots(3^{2^{n-1}}+1)=3^{2^n}-1,
$$
so
$$
b_n=\frac{3^{2^n}-1}{3^{2^n}+1},
$$
and therefore,
$$
\frac{1+b_n}{1-b_n}=3^{2^n}=\left(3^{2^{n-1}}\right)^2=\left(\frac{1+b_{n-1}}{1-b_{n-1}}\right)^2.
$$
Thus,
$$
b_n=\frac{\left(\frac{1+b_{n-1}}{1-b_{n-1}}\right)^2-1}{\left(\frac{1+b_{n-1}}{1-b_{n-1}}\right)^2+1}=\frac{(1+b_{n-1})^2-(1-b_{n-1})^2}{(1+b_{n-1})^2+(1-b_{n-1})^2}=\frac{4b_{n-1}}{2+2b_{n-1}^2}=\frac{2b_{n-1}}{1+b_{n-1}^2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n-1 =(a_{n-1}-1)^2 = (a_{n-2}-1)^{2^2} =... = (a_{0}-1)^{2^n}
\Longrightarrow \color{red}{a_n = (a_{0}-1)^{2^n}+1 = 3^{2^n}+1}$$

Then
$$b_{n+1} = \frac{2a_0a_1a_2...a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{2a_0a_1a_2...a_{n-1}}{a_n} \cdot\frac{a_n^2}{a_{n+1}} = \color{red}{b_n\cdot \frac{\left(3^{2^n}+1\right)^2}{3^{2^{n+1}}+1}}$$